# GParted doesn't recognize my newly resized vdi

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, gparted, resize2fs

Before I describe the problem, I'd like to specify that I'm not confused about the size of the partitions (they haven't been extended yet, so of course they haven't grown) but the size of the actual device GParted sees.

I had a `vdi` file with ArchLinux installed. The size was 8GB. I extended this to 20GB, which I can confirm in the VirtualBox GUI on my host.

However, after having loaded the GParted live cd into the VM and booting into it, it says that `/dev/sda` is an 8GB device. It won't let me resize anything because it doesn't think the drive actually got any bigger.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I resized the base image `vdi` of my virtual hard drive. However, I was using a snapshot. I found the right `vdi` corresponding to the snapshot and resized that instead.

Comment: So what happened to original vdi, did you able to shrink it back? Or you left it alone. I am having same issue.

Comment: Yeah. I'm confused about how VirtualBox handles snapshots. I had assumed that snapshots were like backups, statically preserving a previous state of the system and only being used when you want to revert back to that system, but, for some reason, VirtualBox labels each virtual machine with the name of the most recent snapshot, despite the fact that it's clearly using a version of the machine including changes made after the snapshot was made. I'm guessing my problem is the same as yours.

Comment: It looks like my understanding was backwards, the "snapshot" is actually the "differencing image" that describes how to the normal .vdi into the up-to-date version you use (so it's more of an anti-snapshot), and the normal .vdi is the backup. VERY confusing and misleading design.

Comment: So, I guess my next question is whether it's necessary to change the size of BOTH the "snapshot" AND the plainly-named .vdi.

Comment: Well, it works if you DO resize all of them, and VirtualBox makes it very difficult to shrink the virtual size of virtual disk drives, even if the space you're "removing" is totally unused and unallocated, so I probably won't find out if you only have to change one.

Comment: If I understand the documentation at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#diffimages , you should (theoretically) only have to resize the virtual size of the most recent differencing image ("snapshot").